# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I am trying a nested reactive form in Angular 4. It is working fine but when I try to build AOT it's throwing the error

> 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

I googled and tried few things but no luck. Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

```html
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="addresses">
      <div *ngFor="let address of myForm.get('addresses').controls; let i=index" 
                  class="panel panel-default">
          <span *ngIf="myForm.get('addresses').length > 1"
                  (click)="removeAddress(i)">Remove</span>
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
              <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput formControlName="city" placeholder="city" value="">
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
  <a (click)="addAddress()" style="cursor: default"> Add +</a>
</div>
```

typescript code below

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {     
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        addresses: this._fb.array([
            this.initAddress(),
        ])
    });
}
initAddress() {
    return this._fb.group({
        city: ['']
    });
}
addAddress() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('addresses');
    control.push(this.initAddress());
}
removeAddress(i: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('addresses');
    control.removeAt(i);
}
```

Comment: I think the preferred way is `myForm.get('addresses')`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do we need to use this in HTML ngFor or in the Typescript ?

Comment: Should work in both if `myForm` is an `AbstractControl`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer updated code in the question as per ur suggestion, its working fine but AOT throw same error :( any idea ? pls chk code

Comment: Then you probably changed it on the wrong place. It's quite unlikely that `get()` throws an error that `controls()` doesn't exist.

Comment: create getter like  `get addressesControls() {
        return (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('addresses')).controls;
    }`  or just use the following `myForm.get('addresses')['controls']`

Comment: @yurzui Thanks just update myForm.get('addresses')['controls'] in HTML , its working fine now

Comment: how this thing will itterate may I know Munna
rentalPricingForm.controls.pricingBundle.controls[i].controls.packageName.errors

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Based on @Günter Zöchbauer  comments , first i changed

`myForm.controls['addresses']` to `myForm.get('addresses')` in both html and typescript

and then based on @yuruzi comment

changed `myForm.get('addresses').controls` to `myForm.get('addresses')['controls']`

Its working fine now. Thanks @gunter & yuruzi

Comment: My case: form.get('user')['controls'].profile. its ok tnks

Comment: This wrked for me seamlessly. Thanks Man! In the tempate ```myForm.get('addresses')['controls']```
In the ts 
```const control = this.myForm.controls.addresses as FormArray```

Comment: Kinda woodoo magic, it must be working without array notation....

Comment: I think @sunnykashyap's answer is preferred by keeping type safety in place.

This way sets the type to 'any' which can still generate type errors (Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"controls"' can't be used to index type 'AbstractControl<any, any>')

Answer (score 117):

You can fix it easily though. Outsource the "get the controls" logic into a method of your component code (the `.ts` file):

```
getControls() {
  return (this.recipeForm.get('controlName') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

In the template, you can then use:

```
*ngFor="let ingredientCtrl of getControls(); let i = index"
```

This adjustment is required due to the way TS works and Angular parses your templates (it doesn't understand TS there).

Comment: Maybe on later angular versions you have to use `return (this.recipeForm.get('controlName') as FormArray).controls;`

Comment: Works Well with Angular 14

Answer (score 13):

Change `myForm.get('addresses').controls` to `myForm.get('addresses').value` will also fix the issue.

Answer (score 12):

As an update to @sunny kashyap solution, I would write it this way:

```js
getControls() {
  return (this.recipeForm.get('controlName') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for validation errors use...

```
<span *ngIf="f.YOUR_FORM_KEY.controls.YOUR_FORM_KEY.errors?.YOUR_FORM_VALIDATION">YOUR_FORM_KEY is YOUR_FORM_VALIDATION</span>
```

eg.

```
<span *ngIf="f.name.controls.name.errors?.required">Name is required</span>
```

ts file

```
get f(): any {
    return this.userForm.controls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the length of a `FormArray` , use simply `length` :

```
<span *ngIf="myForm.controls['addresses'].length > 1" (click)="removeAddress(i)">Remove</span>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. But It doesn't fix issue.

Comment: Yes @mohammed,  pls chk the updated code in question

Comment: can you please try this  `let address of  myForm.controls.addresses.controls` instead of `let address of 
myForm.get('addresses').controls`

Answer (score 0):

Can use a custom interface

```
// Define AbstractFormGroup
export interface AbstractFormGroup extends FormGroup {
  controls: {
    [key: string]: AbstractFormGroup & AbstractFormGroup[] & AbstractControl & FormGroup & FormArray,
  }
}

// Usage example
class ... {
  myForm: AbstractFormGroup
  ...
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({...}) as AbstractFormGroup
}
```