# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

**when we use setvalue in for loop.**

Every thing is fine but it gives error:-

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Angular 6
How we solve this..

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.experience.length; i++) 
  { 
     if ( i !== 0 ){ 
       const control = <FormArray>this.expGroup.controls['expArray'];
       control.push(this.getExp()); 
     }
  this.expArray.at(i).controls['company_Name'].setValue(this.experience[i].company_Name);
  this.expArray.at(i).controls['position'].setValue(this.experience[i].position); 

  this.expArray.at(i).controls['employee_id'].setValue(this.experience[i].employee_id); 

  this.expArray.at(i).controls['time_prefered'].setValue(this.experience[i].time_prefered);   this.expArray.at(i).controls['work_exp_year'].setValue(this.experience[i].work_exp_year);   this.expArray.at(i).controls['date_of_joining'].setValue(this.experience[i].date_of_joining);   
  this.expArray.at(i).controls['id'].setValue(this.experience[i].id);    
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `this.expArray` ? is it a form array ?

Comment: it's better to use a getter in this case like `this.expGroup.get(`expArray.${index}.company_Name`).setValue(this.experience[i].company_Name)` .

Comment: yes it a formarray

Comment: i will try but it works fine.

Comment: Thanku so much sir  its work properly after doing this this.expArray.at(i).get('company_Name').setValue(this.experience[i].company_Name);

Comment: Ok , I will post this as answer , can you accept it ?

Comment: Posted as answer

Comment: Can use a [custom interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614356/1669165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly accessing the `controls` property of each `FormArray` element , it recommended to use a getter to access the required control from the `FormArray` . While iterating the `FormArray` by index it exposes each array element as type of `AbstractControl` which directly does not have access to the `controls` property. Hence you can use the below code -

```
this.expArray.at(i).get('company_Name').setValue(this.experience[i].company_Name);
```

to set value to the each control inside the FormArray.

Here is the complete code -

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.experience.length; i++) 
      { 
         if ( i !== 0 ){ 
           const control = <FormArray>this.expGroup.controls['expArray'];
           control.push(this.getExp()); 
         }
     this.expArray.at(i).get('company_Name').setValue(this.experience[i].company_Name); 
     this.expArray.at(i).get('position').setValue(this.experience[i].position); 

     this.expArray.at(i).get('employee_id').setValue(this.experience[i].employee_id); 

     this.expArray.at(i).get('time_prefered').setValue(this.experience[i].time_prefered);
     this.expArray.at(i).get('work_exp_year').setValue(this.experience[i].work_exp_year);
     this.expArray.at(i).get('date_of_joining').setValue(this.experience[i].date_of_joining);   
     this.expArray.at(i).get('id').setValue(this.experience[i].id);    

   }
```

Comment: There is some problem to setValue to checkbox. i will provide u stackblitz link to review.