# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I keep getting the same build error when I run **ng build -aot** 
The build error says **Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.**

My Form looks like this
[component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtN82.png)

And the HTML look like this
[component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnsRP.png)

Comment: Hello. Please post the code instead of an image to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46926182/property-controls-does-not-exist-on-type-abstractcontrol-angular-4)

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of chaining!

`FromGroup` has an attribute of the form `controls: { [key: string]: AbstractControl; }`. This means that, in your HTML, when you write `createUserForm.controls.password`, the AOT compiler understands that it is an object of type `AbstractControl` - which, in turn, does *not* declare an attribute named `controls`!

Right now, there's no way for the compiler to understand that your `password` group is an actual `FormGroup` - all it understands is that it is an `AbstractControl`(which may be a control, a group or an array). In order to show the AOT compiler that `password` is, in fact, a group, you can declare a helper getter in your component file:

```
get passwordGroup(): FormGroup { return this.createUserForm.controls.password as FormGroup; }
```

and then you can go to your HTML file and properly find your subcontrols:

```
<app-validation-messages [control]="passwordGroup.controls.password" ></app-validation-messages>
```

All that said, I personally dislike the use of nested groups and controls like that. You could have instead made your `app-validation-messages` component implement the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface as well as make it provide  the [NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR](https://angular.io/api/forms/NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) token. Doing that, you can then control the value using the `formGroupName` and `formControlName` directives:

```
<div formGroupName="password">
  <app-validation-messages formControlName="password"></app-validation-messages>
</div>
```