# TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

Tags: angular, controls

I'm busy with the 'Angular - The Complete Guide (2021 Edition)' on Udemy and have run into a bit of an issue:

I keep getting the following error: TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'
I'm working with the latest version of Angular.

Here is my HTML code:

```
                    <div class="row" *ngFor="let ingredient of recipeForm.get('ingredients').controls; let i = index"
                        [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
```

Any advise will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you try: `(recipeForm.get('ingredients') as any).controls` ?. You have to provide TS file of your component that can some one help you.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46928219/6513921

Answer (score 1):

```
      <div
        class="row"
        *ngFor="let ingredientCtrl of recipeForm.get('ingredients')['controls']; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
        style="margin-top: 10px;">
```

// just use ['Controls'] instead of .Controls

Comment: really you should use a getter to get the array `get ingredientsArray(){return this.form.get('ingredients') as FormArray}` and use `ingredientsArray.controls`